# Where is the content of the Control Panel stored in Sitecore 9.2

Tags: sitecore-client, upgrade

I have performed an upgrade of a solution from 8.2 to 9.2 but can still see some differences in the Control Panel between the upgraded one and a clean instance created by SIF.

I have tried synchronising this item

```
/sitecore/client/Applications/ControlPanel
```

from the Core DB, but it doesn't seem to have had any effect. Is there some other place where this is defined in the Core DB or is it in fact a file system artefact which has been missed?

[image]

Comment: Are you logged in with Admin User after the upgrade? Is there any permission issue? Can you check your user with the Sitecore Vanilla Admin user and see if any role is missing?

Comment: Have you tried the SPE control panel integration?

Comment: @SumitBhatia there are no custom roles or anything else assigned to the admin user accounts in either upgraded or vanilla instances. Both accounts have the Administrator checkbox checked.

Comment: @MatthewDresser its defined under `/sitecore/content/Applications/Control Panel`, try to reindex the core database and check you have `/sitecore/content/Applications/Control Panel/Administration/Administration tools` item in core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control Panel in Sitecore uses `sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ControlPanel\ControlPanel.cshtml` file, So if you will see the code in this file, it just reads all the children of item ID - `{AD6A5F44-088A-450E-9DBE-75DDADC94C57}` and create the complete page. This ID is control panel item in core database on following path - `/sitecore/content/Applications/Control Panel`. you are not able to see the  `Administration tools` so you need to check and sync `/sitecore/content/Applications/Control Panel/Administration` item and its children.

Comment: OMG How did I not see that item before? I swear I looked in that *exact* location, I think the Icon must have thrown me or something...